# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Could not resolve all files for configuration

Tags: flutter, apache, gradle, dependencies, flutter-dependencies

I have problem when i installing some dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  youtube_player_iframe: ^2.2.2
```

when i run my flutter and throw some error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_local_notifications:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_local_notifications:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not download threetenbp-1.4.2-no-tzdb.jar (org.threeten:threetenbp:1.4.2)
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/threeten/threetenbp/1.4.2/threetenbp-1.4.2-no-tzdb.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/threeten/threetenbp/1.4.2/threetenbp-1.4.2-no-tzdb.jar'.
            > This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server (repo.maven.apache.org)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: As mentioned here
** did not receive a response from an authoritative server (repo.maven.apache.org)**

maybe you forget to add maven dependency to your gradle file or maybe the network connection lost 

please add your gradle files content to the post to figure it out with you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Turn off firewall and this work :)**